# How can i program a database driven iOS, Android, ... App Using Adobe Dreamweaver 6 and phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, database, cordova, dreamweaver

Since i am new in Phone app programming, this might be a silly question...
But I am trying to develop an iOS and may be also Android English-Amharic Dictionary app that needs an internal database.

By internal Database I mean a the application don't need to connected to any network or Internet

The Dictionary definitions must initially be loaded into database and shipped with the app

The user might highlight/bookmark definitions. so there is also "Insert INTO..."

I am using dreamweaver as a development tool along with phonegap.

1. What type of database can I choose? SQLite, XML, Core Data,...? Which one is the best?
2. How do i Start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I assume since you are using phonegap you are looking at developing with html and javascript so I would recommend html5 local storage [here's a link](http://www.aquim.com/web-article-237.html). Or just google html5 local storage or something like that.

Comment: hey, Thank you for the quick response. Here is the thing, I want to preload the dictionary data into database before the app is installed. Is that posible? i mean can i create a database file of html5 local storage and ship it with may app?

Comment: how big would this data be?.. maybe you could just store it as json and store it as a string in there database. I don't think there is anyway to prepopulate it other  than just storing value key pairs a bunch of times on load up if they don't have the data.

Comment: it's actually big, i mean its a dictionary! But lets say i could write the value key pairs for each definition, doesn't it have a performance issue considering the javascript file will take considerably large space and it has to be loaded on memory each time the app is loaded?

Comment: well it would be only once since it's persistent and all of that data is saved locally on the hard drive. I would definitely say it would be a performance issue on load up the first time unless you some how dynamically load it up as say the user uses other parts of your site.

Comment: Thank You so much You Have Much Help... I Will add a comment if something came up that i need help with!!!

Comment: Sure no problem. I would recommend accepting one of the answers on here though because some people may avoid answering your future questions if you don't accept them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend that you do is read the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html). There is even a section on [Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) that seems to imply that you must use either a variation of SQL or HTML local storage

Comment: Hey, thank u for the quick response too. the documentation did not answer me my above comment, please read it and get back to me! when i "Create Database" Where does the database file found... i just need the basics.